# Differentiation and series expansion of dot product - inconsistent results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, series-expansion, differentials

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3 or later**

**Bug resolved in 12.0**

As of 12.0, we have an unevaluated result - inconsistent with the differentiation result, but not invalid.

```
SeriesCoefficient[a.b[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* SeriesCoefficient[a.b[x], {x, 0, 1}] *)
```

---

If I differentiate a dot product, I get the result I expect

```
D[a.b[x], x]
(* a.b'[x] *)
```

However, a series expansion of the same expression (V9-V11) gives a very different result

```
SeriesCoefficient[a.b[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* a.1 b'[0] *)
```

Is there any logical explanation of this behaviour?

**EDIT**

This has been confirmed as a bug by Wolfram support.

Comment: attempts to work with abstract vectors in mathematica are usually not fruitful.  Note that second strange result can never be evaluated since `Dot` with a integer is not defined

Comment: bug present in 11.1.0

Comment: I think the "edit" part should be in the answer, not the question.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. One might regard it as a limitation that `Series` was not designed (or implemented) to work with `Dot`. But that in and of itself is not a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - If Mathematica returns an expression unevaluated, that isn't a bug.  If it returns a result that I don't expect, but has a reasonable and logical explanation, that isn't a bug.  Here, Mathematica has evaluated a reasonable input and returned a result that nobody has argued is logically correct.  Therefore (as the email I had from Wolfram support agreed) I classify it as a bug.

Comment: It's basically behaving the same as `SeriesCoefficient[dot[a, b[x]], {x, 0, 1}]` (so I am claiming it is logically correct).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug by Wolfram support.

(Bug still present in 11.0.0)

Answer (score 3):

You can muck about with an internal function to get [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) to work a bit better on [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) (and [`Cross`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cross) etc) products. For example:

```
protect = Unprotect[System`Private`InternalSeries];
System`Private`InternalSeries[a_Dot, {x_, x0_, n_Integer?NonNegative}] := Module[
    {d = NestList[D[#, x]&, a, n], res},

    res = Quiet @ Check[d /. x->x0, $Failed];
    SeriesData[x, x0, TensorExpand @ res, 0, n+1, 1] /; res =!= $Failed
]
Protect @@ protect;
```

Now, your example works correctly:

```
SeriesCoefficient[a.b[x],{x,0,1}]
```

> a.b'[0]

A more complicated example:

```
Series[Exp[a[x].b[x]+x^2], {x, 0, 2}] //TeXForm
```

> $e^{a(0).b(0)}+x e^{a(0).b(0)} \left(a'(0).b(0)+a(0).b'(0)\right)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 e^{a(0).b(0)}
>    \left(\left(a'(0).b(0)+a(0).b'(0)\right)^2+2 \left(a''(0).b(0)+2
>    a'(0).b'(0)+a(0).b''(0)+1\right)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$

Where this modification won't help is when the series is not a Taylor or MacLaurin series, e.g., a Laurent or Puiseaux series.